# How to edit SVG from its URL

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React.js project where I have used an Image component to display my svg (by creating the src of the Image my svg)

```
{selectedHost && <Image 
     className="bg-white w-full h-full p-2 rounded-lg border-black border-2" 
     src={selectedHost.store_map_url} //THIS IS WHERE THE URL IS 
     alt='Store map' 
     width={500} 
     height={500} />}
 </div>`
```

It is requested that we create a feature that greys out certain areas of the svg file. Since we are fetching the url from a database, I am having issues accessing the editable html/css of the file from the url. If I had the actual SVG file inside my code, it would be easier. But, since I am working with just the URL, it is making it difficult.

I have tried things such as just copying and pasing the svg code as a component into the react project, but it doesn't allow for us to have multiple svgs.

Comment: How many different areas can become grey?